# Prevent auto-scrolling to top before sliding to new page JqueryMobile

Tags: html, listview, css, jquery-mobile, collapsable

I have several collapsible blocks (divs) in my page with listviews inside them. The lists are pretty long (about 100-200 elements each.) When I un-collapse a block, scroll down a page, and click/tap one of the element in the list, the page scrolls to the top before sliding to the next page.

This behavior is somehow annoying and doesn't look good. I there any way to prevent this behavior?

If you have any additional question about my post, don't hesitate to ask me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone on this. is more information needed? Let me know.

Comment: I think the scrolltop is necessary because transitions mean: a new page is loaded, pulled up on the right side of the current page and then slid over to replace the current page.  
To see this, try shrinking your page to 50% width and set _position:static_ and then changePage. I think it would really mess up the layout if you pulled in a new page at your current viewport position. I guess that's why the current page scrolls to the top before the new page is inserted into the viewport. Not much help, but a little explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a link with "#" as href, it will jump up to the top of the page, however if you add "return false;" after the exectution of your code, it won't jump up. Example:

```
<script>
function test(){
alert('It works!'); // Just a simple function
}
</script>

<!-- Div to make the page scrollable -->

<div style="margin-top:1000px;height:1px;width:1px;"></div>

<a href="#" onClick="test(); return false;">Yay</a>
<!-- Triggering the test function and not jumping up to the top -->
```

I'm not sure if this is what you were thinking about though.

Comment: Also, you can use event.preventDefault() on jQuery.